# Custom Button with a Viewbox inside

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have this style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                <Border>                 
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Viewbox x:Name="ViewBoxInternal" Child="{TemplateBinding Child}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockInternal" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I have two dependency properties.

```
static ImageButton()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));

    ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Child", typeof(UIElement), typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
    TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Button"));
}
```

I can set the `Text` property without a problem, but somehow I can't set the Child of my `Viewbox`.
The `Viewbox` should receive a `Canvas` as a `Child`.

Calling this way, gives me an error:

```
<custom:ImageButton Text="New" Width="41" Child="{StaticResource NewIcon}"/>
```

*Unable to cast object of 'System.Windows.TemplateBindingExpression' to type 'System.Windows.UIElement'.*

### Now, working...

As @Xaml-Lover said, you need this:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="ViewBoxInternal">
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="{TemplateBinding Content}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
</Viewbox>
```

And you need to call like this:

```
<custom:ImageButton Text="New" Content="{StaticResource NewIcon}" />
```

[image: VOÀLA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, the Child property of Viewbox is not a Dependency Property. A binding can only set to a Dependency property. I would suggest you to follow a different approach. Use ContentPresenter as a place holder for Child property and wrap it in a a Viewbox.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="ViewBoxInternal">
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Child"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But for a strange reason, I have to set `Child="{StaticResource NewIcon}"` as `Content`, even with the template binding as `Child`.